# Trigonometry Proving

Tags: trigonometry

1. If $\sin\theta + \sin\alpha=x$ and $\cos\theta + \cos\alpha=y$, prove that ; $$\frac{\tan(\theta - \alpha)}{2} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{4-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$

Attempts:
Here $\sin\theta + \sin\alpha=x$
          squaring both sides, we get
 $$\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta \sin\alpha+ \sin^2\alpha=x^2 \tag{1}$$

Again, squaring the second condition, we get;
$$\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta\cdot \cos\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=y^2\tag2$$

Also, adding (1) and (2), and solving a bit I got,
$$\cos\theta\cdot \cos\alpha+\sin\theta\cdot \sin\alpha=(x^2+y^2-2)/2$$

My effort ends up here. Now how should I complete?

Comment: The numerator under the square root is 2 - 2cos(theta - alpha). The denominator is 2(1+cos(theta - alpha))

Comment: I'll just write theta as a and alpha as b

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by denominator. Fraction is now sin(a-b)/1+cos(a-b). It becomes tan((a-b)/2)

Comment: I think the 2 should be inside the tan function.

Comment: @user, yes you are right..

Comment: Just one more elaboration. Expand sin(a-b) as 2sin((a-b)/2)cos((a-b)/2). And 1 + cos(a-b) = 2cos^2((a-b)/2). Cancel out the common factor 2cos((a-b)/2) and you are left with tan(a-b)/2.

Comment: Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need $$\tan\dfrac{\theta-\alpha}2$$

Now use $$\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$$

and $$\cos2u=\dfrac{1-\tan^2u}{1+\tan^2u}\iff\tan^2u=\dfrac{1-\cos2u}{1+\cos2u}$$

Comment: I could not get it, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, Set $A=\theta, B=\alpha$  and then $$2u=\theta-\alpha$$